# Can anyone explain this way of including two classes at a time in javascript

Tags: reactjs

```
label ? (<label className={`${otherProps.value.length ? 'shrink' : ''} form-input-label`}>
{label}
</label>) : null
```

I am not getting how the class is being applied

Comment: It's just a template literal string (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), inside which there is a ternary operator that determines whether to not to add the "shrink" class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

```
>  label && (<label className={`${otherprops.value.length} ? 'shrink' :
> 'form-input-label'`}>{label}</label>)
```

> Based on the question you've asked, if the value of label is true
> then, it checks inside, the value of the class name and will be
> 'shrink' in case of true, otherwise the class name will be
> 'form-input-label in case of false. And if the label is false, then
> will return null. You can update you code as like above, that i have
> mentioned for easy it directly checks for the true case only!! Hope
> that this will make clear!

Comment: Answer implies more in-depth explanatory of what these lines of code does. Please in the near future try avoiding posting simply the code without any explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

The `className` will be

- `'shrink form-input-label'` if `otherProps.value.length` value is true value (maybe `otherProps.value` isn't empty string or array)
- `' form-input-label'` if `otherProps.value.length` is false value (`otherProps.value` is empty string or array)